# PHPDoc: How to document different class property options

Tags: php, phpdoc

Is there any way with phpdoc to document the different values that a class property can take and what effect this will have. For example:-

```
class SomeClass {

   /**
   * Cell text align
   * 
   * null - table default
   * l - left align
   * r - right align
   * c - centre align
   * j - justify
   */
   public $align;

   Some code
}
```

Is there any way to make the value-description pairs be parsed by phpdoc so that it will turn them into a definition list or such like?

Comment: Unrelated: how do you intend to ensure that the variable contains these values? Have you thought about a protected variable with public getters and setters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will become a `<ul>` in the documentation output:

```
class SomeClass {

   /**
    * Cell text align
    * 
    * Possible values: 
    * - null - table default
    * - l - left align
    * - r - right align
    * - c - centre align
    * - j - justify
    */
   public $align;

   // Some code
}
```

From [the manual page on DocBlock description details](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.howto.pkg.html).

Comment: Soon we'll be able to look forward to PHPDocumentor 2 @ www.phpdoc.org, though it's not finished just yet as of this post.